# Rails: which test method to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I want to write some tests for my current project.

These tests will be mostly related to saved data in the database.

For example:

- If a user registered `7` years ago, provide him `gold badge` (a boolean
  field set to true)
- If registered `3` years ago then `bronze badge` etc.

Well, the calculations are bit more complicated before the boolean field is set to true. There are about `30-40` test cases that I need to test which are very similar to the above two examples.

I did some reading about *Rails* testing but I could not figure out the exact difference between integration, unit and functional testing in *Rails*.

In my case which testing method will be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends how you would implement it.

If you're using a cronjob to check for users badges an integration test would be good, to test the whole job enqueuing and stuff.

If you're updating when the user logs in, you can use a model (unit) test.
For example:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "users badge is updated on login if needed" do
    user = User.create ... , golden_badge: false
    travel_to Time.now + 7.years do
      # simulate login, something like: user.login(user: "", pass: "")
      assert user.golden_badge
    end
  end
end
```

this test would take place in `test/models/user_test.rb`

Answer (score 0):

It depends where exactly the code that updates this field is executed. For example if you check these 'rewards' on the update of a user in user model itself as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_rewards

  def check_rewards
    self.update(golden_badge: true) if created_at > 5.years.ago
  end
```

Then the tests would only need to take place in the models/user_spec.rb which is a unit test.

If the code was ran as a cron job every hour, which used a method in a file called check_rewards.rb that would probably belong in two places.

Firstly the 'unit' test of the object that does the updating in services/check_rewards.rb (or commands/check_rewards.rb, or whatever directory) to test the actual functionality is working, like my user spec code above.

Finally you should have an integration test in integration/check_rewards_spec.rb to ensure that the job manager you are using is working as expected, so that the job itself is actually run and has the expected behavior.

Comment: before_save is rarely called on a user I think.
It would be really awkward if the user updates his email, and then would receive the badge :grin:

Comment: It's rarely called without a condition, I over simplified this. I often do before_save :do_somthing if :should_do_something? for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing : For testing smallest unit of code. For a specific functionality. Like CRUD operation testing in a controller. Each action will test in unit testing separately.

Integration Testing : For testing a group of functionality or module. Consider if you want to see what a simple user can see and what logged in user can see in a website. So in both cases you need to test login functionality then a particular functionality after that.

Functional testing is completely different. In this you can test either module or combination of modules. It more like to integration testing.

`Unit tests tell a developer that the code is doing things right; functional tests tell a developer that the code is doing the right things.`

Read more [here](http://www.softwaretestingtricks.com/2007/01/unit-testing-versus-functional-tests.html)

In my view you should go for functional testing.